# Setting token and header in rspec test for JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, json-api

I'm trying to test a json written in rails in rspec. I'm not sure about the syntax. This is what I have so far:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::VersionsController, :type => :controller do

  before do
    @token = "0"
    request.env["Content-Type"] = 'application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8'
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the index JSON" do
      @request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8'
      request.env['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8'
      params = { token: @token }
      get :index, :format => :json, token: @token
      #response.should be_success
      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      ap body
    end
  end
end
```

I tried it in a bunch of different ways as you can see. But I'm getting a 403 error.

I'm using `Rails 5.0.0.beta3`, `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]` and `rspec-3.1`.

Comment: Can we see your controller code and the methods its using to authenticate a request?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, the problem was not with my code, but the fact that my test database was not populated with the token. I had a rake task for this and just running it with RAILS_ENV=test solved the issue. Also the code in my question is not very clean as I'm trying a bunch of different stuff to achieve the same result. Here's the final spec for anyone who might be interested:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::VersionsController, :type => :controller do

  before do
    @token = "0"
    @request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8'
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the index JSON" do
      get :index, :format => :json, token: @token
      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
      expect(body["meta"]["app_name"]).to eq Rails.application.class.parent_name
      expect(body["meta"]["app_version"]).to eq ApplicationName.version
    end
  end

end
```